# How to select specific columns and get data from those columns and store them in different columns in another table? (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

hope you all are doing well. I have two tables in my database purchase__request and purchase_order. So what I was trying to do is get the data from the columns item_name, description, item_qty, and dep_name whose `status ='Approved'` from the `purchase__request` table. And then store them in the `purchase_order` table with column names as follows: item_name, description, item_qty, dep_name; and still be able to fill in the other columns in this (purchase_order) table.
So when I use the following code below it shows me this Error:

> Attempt to assign property "[{"item_name":"Paper","description":"A4
> size","item_qty":15,"dep_name":"Accounting &
> Finance"},{"item_name":"d","description":"a","item_qty":4,"dep_name":"Accounting
> & Finance"}]" on null

PO.blade.php:

```
<form action="{{url('/addPO')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="po_date">Order Date <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="date" class="po_date" id="po_date" name="po_date" required="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table text-start align-middle table-bordered table-hover mb-0">
            <thead>
                <tr class="text-dark">
                    <th scope="col">PR ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Item Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                    <th scope="col">Department</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach($PO as $PO)
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{$PO->PR_id}}" hidden="" />{{$PO->PR_id}}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{$PO->item_name}}" hidden="" />{{$PO->item_name}}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{$PO->item_name}}" hidden="" />{{$PO->description}}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{$PO->item_qty}}" hidden="" />{{$PO->item_qty}}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{$PO->dep_name}}" hidden="" />{{$PO->dep_name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="sum">Sum<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="number" class="sum" id="sum" name="sum" required="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="vat">Vat<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="number" class="vat" id="vat" name="vat" required="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label" for="approved_by">Approved By<span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" class="approved_by" id="approved_by" name="approved_by" required="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Routes:

```
Route:: view('addPO', 'admin.PO');

Route::post('/addPO', [AdminController::class, 'addDataOrder']);
```

My function in AdminController:

```
public function addDataOrder(Request $request)
{
    $PO = new purchase_order();
    $PO->po_date = $request->po_date ;
    $PO->sum = $request->sum ;
    $PO->vat = $request->vat;
    $PO->approved_by = $request->approved_by ;
    
    $PO = DB::table("purchase__requests")->select('item_name','description','item_qty','dep_name')->where('status', 'Approved')->get();
    
    foreach($PO as $key->$PO){ 
        DB::table("purchase_order")->insert(
        [
            'item_name' => $PO->item_name,
            'description' => $PO->description,
             'item_qty ' => $PO->item_qty, 
            'dep_name ' => $PO->dep_name,
        ]);   
    }

    $PO->save();
    
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Please help me I'm new to Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses Models as associations with database tables. You can read more here - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#introduction. Bookmark the Laravel docs, they are very useful.

From what I can see so far, you will need two new models - `PurchaseRequest` and `PurchaseOrder`

As in Laravel's docs, you can create a model with the artisan command:
`php artisan make:model PurchaseRequest`

Also, your `purchase__requests` table should be renamed to `purchase_requests` (single underline instead of two).

You really need to read at least some of the Laravel docs to be productive with Laravel. I hope you take your time to at least read the link I've sent you.

Anyway, after you create your models, you could then save the purchase order this way:

```
$purchaseOrder = new PurchaseOrder();
$purchaseOrder->po_date = $request->po_date;
$purchaseOrder->sum = $request->sum;
// and so on for other fields, then we save the model and this will write the data to the database
$purchaseOrder->save();
```

You should also do some validation for the `$request` variable to make sure that you don't save invalid stuff, such as the `po_date` being a thousand years in the past, etc. You can read more about how to do validation with Laravel here - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#main-content